# Laravel 5.1 query has undesired "limit 1"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

This never happened to me before

```
return $this->model->newQuery()
    ->where('canonical', true)
    ->groupBy('systemUrl')
    ->having('n', '>', 1)
    ->select('systemUrl', \DB::raw('count(*) as n'))
    ->pluck('systemUrl')->toArray();
```

This code produces the desired query, except it output an unexpected `limit 1`.

How is that possible?

Comment: because i want that query to output an array of systemUrl(s). Combining select and pluck not possible?

Comment: i've done this many times guys, $model->join(anything)->where(something)->pluck('column')->toArray(), it will return ['data1', 'data2', ..., 'datan']

Comment: Ok i've got it. In order to obtain that i need to plug a get() before the pluck(), like $model->where(anyhing)->get()->pluck('column')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was a missing `get()`:

```
return $this->model->newQuery()
    ->where('canonical', true)
    ->groupBy('systemUrl')
    ->having('n', '>', 1)
    ->select('systemUrl', \DB::raw('count(*) as n'))
    ->get() // <--- this one
    ->pluck('systemUrl')->toArray();
```